# how do i create a AWS Lambda function for notifying the owner of the stack for its retirement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am trying to create a lambda function for aws cloudformation which will take the retirementDate parameter and notify the user of the stack's retirement.
or will assign 'deadManSwitchDate' tag to the stack, if no action taken.

I have fetched the retirement date using boto3. How do I proceed further?

```
import boto3  
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')  
stack_list=['NonProd-MPCS-REG']  
for stackname in stack_list:  
    cf_details = client.describe_stacks(StackName = stackname)['Stacks']:  
     for parameters in cf_details:  
        for tag in parameters['Parameters']:  
            if tag['ParameterKey'] == 'RetirementDate':  
                print(tag['ParameterValue'])
```

**Update:**

The `tag['ParameterValue']` was in string `01/15/2019` and I was trying to convert into date format.

```
if tag['ParameterKey'] == 'DeadManSwitchDate':  
    retirement_date.append(tag['ParameterValue'])  
    for i in retirement_date:  
        dead_date=datetime.strptime('i','%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

I am getting the below error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
>       (data_string, format))
>   ValueError: time data 'ParameterValue' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: What do you _want_ it to do next? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried assigning the retirement day i got from the stack;s Parameters details with the below code but i am getting an error:
retirment_date.append(tag['ParameterValue'])
date=datetime().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
>>>

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code rather than trying to put code in a comment. Also, please include a sample value you have stored in the `RetirementDate` parameter.

Comment: The line `strptime('i','%d/%m/%Y').date()` should use `i` rather than `'i'`.